# How to stop (aquamacs) emacs opening all new buffers in new (gui) window/emacs frame?

Tags: buffers, window, frames, aquamacs

I've just upgraded my aquamacs installation and a bunch of packages, and now emacs is opening every new buffer in a new (gui) window (aka emacs frame). I don't like this. I want to have every buffer open in a new tab within the same frame.

I already have this tabbar and window config, but it's not doing the trick:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(pop-up-frames nil)
 '(pop-up-windows nil))

(use-package tabbar
  :ensure t
  :config
  (tabbar-mode 't))
```

How do I keep my buffers all in one frame?

I'm using version: Aquamacs 3.5  GNU Emacs 25.3.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0, NS appkit-1504.83 Version 10.12.6)

Comment: Perhaps the value of `pop-up-frames` is being set to a non-nil value *after* your `custom-set-variables` statement is processed during startup.  What is the value of `pop-up-frames` after startup finishes?  Type `C-h v` aka `M-x describe-variable`

Comment: The distinct feature of Aquamacs has always been (as far as I can remember, that is) a built-in `tabbar`.  https://github.com/aquamacs-emacs/aquamacs-emacs/tree/aquamacs3/aquamacs/src/site-lisp/tabbar  As such, you probably should consider removing the `tabbar` statement in your user-config when using Aquamacs.

Answer (score 1):

The customization I want is:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(one-buffer-one-frame-mode nil nil (aquamacs-frame-setup)))
```

Instead of: `(one-buffer-one-frame-mode t nil (aquamacs-frame-setup)))`